# How can I detect the particular given dropbox path is file or not using android core API?

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I want to detect a particular `dropbox` path is file or not using `android core API`.how come this possible ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203770805-How-can-i-detect-the-particular-given-path-is-file-or-not-using-dropbox-android-core-API- ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### *I found the snippet*

> The [isDir](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.Entry.html#isDir) field on [DropboxAPI.Entry](https://www.dropboxstatic.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.Entry.html) tells you if the Entry is a file
>   or folder.

```
        // Get the metadata for a directory
        Entry dirent = mApi.metadata(mPath, 1000, null, true, null);

        if (!dirent.isDir || dirent.contents == null) {
            // It's not a directory, or there's nothing in it
            mErrorMsg = "File or empty directory";
        }
```

> Also posting Directory create and delete methods available in DropboxAPI

```
mApi.createFolder(directory_path);
mApi.delete(directory_or_file_path);
```

**Thank you.**